# TortoiseHg unshelve Fail/Abort

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I just committed changes to a mercurial repository (VS 2010 C#/WPF if that matters).  I had to merge with the tip to push my changes and not create a new tip, so I shelved the rest of my changes and successfully merged.  As I suspected, the merge wiped out the changes I still had to commit, so I went to go unshelf my changes, and I'm getting unshelf abort, and then failed at hunk 1, etc. for a bunch of files :\ The problem is they are all `<filename>.g.cs`, `<filename>.runtimecache`, etc., i.e. runtime stuff.  There's only about 4 files that I need to recover from my shelf file.

Do I have any hopes of recovering those changes from my shelf file? There's a solid half day's work there and I'd hate to lose it.

I'm using TortoiseHg. Thanks!

Comment: Files that are generated shouldn't end up being tracked by your SCM in the first place.

Comment: As s.m. said, you should have mercurial ignore *.g.cs, *.runtimecache files and any other files generated from your source.  See [.hgignore documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore) for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version 2, you should be able to see the things you shelved and be able to unshelve only those you're interested in.

Comment: I'm using Mercurial 1.7...if I upgrade to 2 will I still be able to access the shelf file and pick which files to unshelf even though it was created in v1.7?

Comment: @user564636: I was talking about TortoiseHG, not Mercurial. If you can, upgrade to 2.1.1, you're using a fairly old version. Do all the backups that need to be done before upgrading (including files needed by TortoiseHG in the `.hg` folder).

Comment: :I was using TortoiseHG 1.1...Well Crap, I upgraded to 2.1.1 and now Trotoise does not even recognize that there is a shelf file... :\

Comment: Well I had no luck in getting the shelf file back.  Luckily I remembered most of what I did and was able to re-do the changes in not that much time. I did upgrade Tortoise so hopefully I can avoid this situation in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @user564636 Ok. Any by all means, pay attention to the files you have under source control. Not every file needs to be tracked, and some **do not** have to be tracked. The rule of thumb is "if a file can be regenerated by a tool, don't track it". Worth reiterating.